# max(df$data==v) returns numeric(0) depending on x,y order in v = c(x,y)

Tags: r

I'm trying to select the maximum between 2 numbers (out of 5) using the following code.

These are the two levels of the column I'm trying to access:

```
lev_opsins_SC = c("SWS2Aa", "SWS2B")
```

They are repeated for each individual (but that loop works).
For each individual I'm trying to tell R to access only the data which correspond to lev_opsins_SC and tell me which one is the max and then store it.

I find out what is the problem but don't know how to fix it:

```
max(df$Rate[df$Specimen=="L20" & df$Opsins == lev_opsins_SC])
[1] 0.509928

max(df$Rate[df$Specimen=="L26" & df$Opsins == lev_opsins_SC])
[1] -Inf
Warning message:
In max(df$Rate[df$Specimen == "L26" & df$Opsins == lev_opsins_SC]) :
no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

These are the output for two different individuals L26 and L20.

I found out that if I change the order of my levels like this:

```
lev_opsins_SC = c("SWS2B", "SWS2Aa")
```

I get the maximum for L26 and the error message for L20.

Any idea why this is happening?
The data is in a .csv file which has the saved with the exact same level order for all individuals.

Full loop (lev_ind is levels for individuals):

```
for (i in lev_ind) {
maximum = max(df$Rate[df$Specimen==i & df$Opsins == lev_opsins_SC])
  for (j in lev_opsins_SC) {
    rate = df$Rate[df$Specimen==i & df$Opsins==j]
    if (rate == maximum) {
      df$Rate[df$Specimen==i & df$Opsins==j] = 1
    } else {
      df$Rate[df$Specimen==i & df$Opsins==j] = (1/(maximum))*rate
    }
  }

 }
return(df)
}
```

Comment: I suspect you expect `==` to work like `%in%` which it doesn't.

Comment: Aaaaaaah thank you so much, works perfectly